# How to display multidimensional array of json string in a table

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I passed data fetched from database via ajax to be displayed in the html page. I managed to pass it in a multidimensional array from php script. Now I get the json string but I'm unsure on how to properly display the output in a html table.

Script

```
$("#submit").on("click",function()
    {

          $("#set_setting").submit(function(){            

            data = $(this).serialize()
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "html",
              url: "submit_setting.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
                  alert(data);
              //hide the form
              $("#set_setting").slideUp("slow");
              //show the result
             /* for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  console.log(data);
                  $(".the-return").html(data);
              }*/

              console.log(data);
                $(".the-return").html(data);

              }

            });
            return false;

          });

        });
```

php script

```
$json=array();
array_push($json,array("type"=>$carType,"maker"=>$carMaker));
echo json_encode($json);
```

Output of data

```
HondaHonda maker[{"type":["flying car","3 wheleer","weird car","miracle car","tata car","see car","star car","mn car","jkcar","car test","ting","Honda"],"maker":["test maker","diamond car","ruby car","dont know car","titi car","saw car","moon car","ty car","ty car","car maker test","ting maker","Honda maker"]}]
```

How do I display this json string in html table?

Comment: var result = data;

$.each($.parseJSON(result), function(k, v) {
    alert(k + ' is ' + v);
});

Comment: then this question is about **JS** and not  **PHP**?!

Comment: Yes it is Js but I still use php to pass the array

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the `Output of Data` that you show is not valid JSON. `HondaHonda maker` should not be there.

Comment: @enhzflep, yes that's right and I removed those two. yet how do I display in proper table?

Comment: @Vani - well, what do you want the table to look like? You have essentially two arrays returned. Do you wish to have a simple 2 column table, with each array in one of the columns?

Comment: @enhzflep, yes I just want to show each array in a column each.

Comment: @Vani - no worries. Just give me a few more minutes. I learned a trick last week or the week before that will help here - namely, the ability to iterate through the properties of an object, without knowing what they're called - in this case, "type" and "maker".

Comment: @enhzflep, oh sure..take your time..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some vanilla JS that will do the trick. It's probably worth mentioning that you're returning an array of results, which only has a single element in it. This is the cause for the `parsedResult[0]` in my code. If you wanted to return the data for multiple html tables, you'd have parsedResult[1], parsedResult[2] etc, etc. This code doesn't account for such a situation - I've hard-coded it to work with just the first.

**Result:** (excuse the text formatting of an html table, if you would)

```
type    maker
flying car  test maker
3 wheleer   diamond car
weird car   ruby car
miracle car dont know car
tata car    titi car
see car saw car
star car    moon car
mn car  ty car
jkcar   ty car
car test    car maker test
ting    ting maker
Honda   Honda maker
```

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag);}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

var dummyResultString = '[{"type":["flying car","3 wheleer","weird car","miracle car","tata car","see car","star car","mn car","jkcar","car test","ting","Honda"],"maker":["test maker","diamond car","ruby car","dont know car","titi car","saw car","moon car","ty car","ty car","car maker test","ting maker","Honda maker"]}]';

function onDocLoaded()
{
    var ajaxResult = dummyResultString;
    var tblOfResults = parseAndCreateTable( ajaxResult );
    document.body.appendChild(tblOfResults);
}

function parseAndCreateTable(inputString)
{
    var rawResult = inputString;
    var parsedResult = JSON.parse(rawResult);
    var tableHeadings = [];

    // extract the name of the properties that the object has.
    for (var property in parsedResult[0]) 
    {
        if (parsedResult[0].hasOwnProperty(property))
            tableHeadings.push(property);
    }

    // make the table
    var tbl = newEl('table');
    var tbody = newEl('tbody');
    tbl.appendChild(tbody);

    // make the first row, with headings in it
    var tr = newEl('tr');
    var i, n = tableHeadings.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        var th = newEl('th');
        th.innerText = tableHeadings[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);

    // now for the 'fun' part - the body itself.
    var curRowIndex, curColIndex, nRows = parsedResult[0][tableHeadings[0]].length, nCols = tableHeadings.length;
    for (curRowIndex=0; curRowIndex<nRows; curRowIndex++)
    {
        var tr = newEl('tr');
        for (curColIndex=0; curColIndex<nCols; curColIndex++)
        {
            var td = newEl('td');
            td.innerText = parsedResult[0][ tableHeadings[curColIndex] ][curRowIndex];
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }

    return tbl; 
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do I need to include any library for this code to work? I've copy pasted this in my success function and it doesn't show anything even with hardcoded value.

Comment: @Vani - nope. There are no dependencies for this code. I've updated my answer to include a fully-functioning example. What did your debugger tell you was the problem?

Comment: no error shown actually..But I included this code  in success function of ajax but you used before head tag...Could this be the reason?  I tried to include it in head section and call the function in success function but still i can't see the table

Comment: Interesting.. Well, you should just pass the results of the ajax call to the `parseAndCreateTable` function and then append the result to the desired container. Actually, my code is _inside_ the head. Something else you could consider is using a jQuery method to set the innerHTML of en element - just get the table from the function call and then get it's html, then use the jQuery method of appending this. I.e `var resultTable = parseAndCreateTable(data); var tblHTML = resultTable.outerHTML; ** set contents of element using jQuery method ** (I dont jQuery, so I dunno what else to suggest)

Comment: I included your function in head and passed data into parseAndCreateTable function then appended into the container just like you mentioned and it returned the table!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something Like this maybe:

```
var typeMsg = ''
var makers = ''
if(data && data[0].type) {                //considering data is your response object
    for(var c in data[0].type) {
        typeMsg += c + ', ';
    }
}
if(data && data[0].maker) {   
    for(var c in data[0].maker) {
        makers += c + ', ';
    }
}

$('#elementForType').text(typeMsg && typeMsg.trim().replace(/,$/, "") + "." || 'No Type data available');
$('#elementForMakers').text(makers && makers.trim().replace(/,$/, "") + "."  || 'No makers data available');
```

Comment: It says, No Type data available
No makers data available

Comment: try data[0].type and data[0].maker

Comment: just do a JSON.stringify(data) and paste the text here. I need to see the response

Comment: [{"type":["4 wheeler","flying ycar"],"maker":["Honda","AUdi"],"rate":[["1","89"],["1","70"],["1","57"],["2","78"],["2","56"],["2","34"]]}]

Comment: I tried and it outputs 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. twice. But what is it? How do I access each element in each array?

Comment: if(data && data[0].type) {                //considering data is your response object
      /*for(var c in data[0].type) {
       typeMsg += c + ', ';
      }*/
      $.each(data[0].type , function( index, value ){
         console.log(value);
         typeMsg += value +',';
       });
      
     }